# How to Re-acquire Data using Linq to SQL?

Tags: c#, linq

Linq to SQL is extremely convenient but how can I re-acquire data with the same DataContext object?

For example, I have a Location table and I write a custom DataContect class to retrieve its data. After I modify its records, is there a way to get the original data without creating another DataContect object?

```
[Table]
class Location
{
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string Place { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "[" + Id + "] " + Place;
    }
}

[Database]
class Database : DataContext
{
    public Database() : base(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AppConnection"].ConnectionString)
    {
    }

    public Table<Location> Locations;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Database db = new Database();
    foreach(var l in db.Locations)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(l);
    }

    // Modify the first record
    var location = db.Locations.First();
    location.Place = "City Hall";

    // How do I retrieve original data before modification?
    var newList = db.Locations;
    foreach (var l in newList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(l);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why can't you do var locations = db.locations.ToList() before you modify your records? Alternatively, if you don't care about preserving your modifications you could use the Refresh() method.

Comment: Thanks. I tried Refresh(RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues, item) and it did work.